# Logout Does not working in Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Logout functionality does not working properly in "Production Environment".

The logout Function is called in Production Environment by `Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 14:48:52 +0530` instead of `Started DELETE "/logout"`.

Note: I don't use Devise Gem in my application.

routes.rb

```
root 'welcome#home'
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :questions

get "quiz/index"

post "quiz/start"

get "quiz/question"

post "quiz/question"

post "quiz/answer"

get "quiz/end"

post "choices/create"

post "choices/destroy"

resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Logout Code:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", logout_path , method: "delete"
```

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your code. Please share some of it, starting with the code code/link that is initiating the logout request.

Comment: I've added some code for your reference which causes the error. 

Note: This code works fine in Development Environment. The problem is with Production Environment itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured the answer for the above Question.

In the Logout Code, instead of `<%= link_to "Log out", logout_path , method: "delete"` use `<%= button_to "Log out", logout_path , method: "delete" %>`.

This one worked for me.

Comment: You changed it from a link to a button? Or am I missing more?